# How to determine initial quantum state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, quantum-states

> A particle in an infinite square well has its initial wave function an
>   even mixture of the first two stationary states:
>   $$\psi(x,0)=A(\psi_1(x)+\psi_2(x)) $$

As you may know, for $\psi(x,t)$ we can write wavefunction with  $c_n\psi_n(x)$, $c_n$ are coefficients of time independent solutions. Thing is finding that coefficients needs initial state that we determine. Thus hypothetically we can say anything for initial state and find its solution via Dirichlet theorem and Schrödinger equation.

For example for finding $A$, simply we could normalize that wavefunction and find $A$ after had $\psi_1(x)$ and $\psi_2(x)$ from Schrödinger.

My question is if we need initial state for finding coefficients of wavefunction then is there fundamental initial state that we can use? Secondly, why initial state of particle in an infinite square well is "$A(\psi_1(x)+\psi_2(x)) $" (Putting A front of that solutions makes them equally probable)?

Comment: The initial state is *specified* here so it isn’t to be determined. Are you asking how to determine the normalization constant $A$? The $A$ is *not* what makes the two states equally probable.

Comment: We determine initial state isn't it? aren't there two constant in that equation one comes from solution of schrödinger and other one comes from c_n - just make sure all superpositioned wavefunctions's sum equals 1. 

My question is why do infinite square well has that initial wave function? I read Griffith and there are tons of different initial conditions but this considered as fundemantal.

Comment: This is a completely arbitrary initial state. What did you read that made you think it is fundamental?

Answer (score 2):

> is there fundamental initial state that we can use?

No. That's a ridiculous question, because the initial state depends on the conditions at which the system was started, and it is generally determined by the preparation procedure.

Put it this way: if you transplant the question to newtonian mechanics you're basically asking something like "I know that $F=ma$ and that this is a differential equation, but is there a fundamental initial position of the particle?" $-$ to which the answer is "no, it depends on where you put it at the start".

Since you don't provide enough context, it's impossible to explain what it is about the wording that gave you this impression, but rest assured that $A(\psi_1(x)+\psi_2(x))$ is **not**, in any way whatsoever, a "fundamental" initial condition for the infinite square well.